# ModuleNotFoundError when attempting to import module from flattened namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Supposing I have a project structure like:

```
proj
   ├── __init__.py
   └── core
      ├── __init__.py
      └── a
         ├── __init__.py
         └── foo.py
```

where the only non-empty files are:

```
# proj/__init__.py
from . core import a
```

and

```
# proj/core/a/__init__.py
from . foo import Bar
```

and

```
# proj/core/a/foo.py
class Bar:
    pass
```

The idea is that I'm lifting the module `a` out of `core` and exposing it in the top-level of the package. However, the following fails:

```
>>> from proj.a import Bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.a'
```

as does:

```
>>> import proj.a.Bar as Bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.a'
```

The following works though if I use the fully qualified module path:

```
>>> from proj.core.a import Bar
```

Two questions:

1. Is there some section of the python documentation that explains why the import/module system doesn't allow the failing cases? I haven't been able to find a clear explanation.
2. Is there a work around so that you can import from `proj.a` as if it were `proj.core.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's get the easy one out of the way: `import proj.a.Bar as Bar` can not work because `Bar` is a class, not a module. `import proj.core.a.Bar as Bar` would not have worked either, for the same reason.

Now for importing from `proj.a`. The "lifting" process that you describe using `__init__.py` files has only created an alias - the entry "a" added in `proj.__dict__` is now bound to a module object, but that in itself does not make does not make the module `proj.core.a` into a direct submodule of `proj`.

The name "a" was just bound in two different *namespaces*: in `proj.__dict__` and in `proj.core.__dict__`. The import statement `from proj.a import Bar` is still processed in the same way as usual, trying to find a module with fully qualified name of `proj.a`. Python will select import machinery from [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) and [`sys.path_hooks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks) (it will use a `PathFinder` and a `FileFinder`), and then search through [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for a dir/subdir like `proj/a`, failing to find one.

> 1. Is there some section of the python documentation that explains why the import/module system doesn't allow the failing cases? I haven't been able to find a clear explanation.

The best I could find was in this section of the import system docs [**5.3. Searching**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching), where it's mentioned that *Python needs the fully qualified name of the module being imported.* The failing case doesn't use the [fully qualified name](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name), it uses some other name.

> 2. Is there a work around so that you can import from `proj.a` as if it were `proj.core.a`?

Yes. Before Python tries to import a module, it first checks if that key was already cached in `sys.modules` dict. Try this workaround:

```
# proj/__init__.py
from . core import a

import sys
sys.modules[f"{__name__}.a"] = a
```

Now `from proj.a import Bar` can succeed, and that works *even if `proj` was not already imported*.

You are hijacking in importlib [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0509c4547fc95cc32a91ac446a26192c3bfdf157/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L973-L975), so **Python actively enables this trick**. There is even [a test case for it working in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/927d87470a0b6f7b0ca3f3a1b39fd3bdc0ec919a), because stdlib xml and etree relies on that behavior too. Though the source code comment does call it "Crazy", so use discretion!